# Declarar evento do textbox no XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

Como eu faço para declarar o evento KeyPressEventArgs de um textbox para trabalhar com esse evento no Code Behind? O código para executar o evento eu tenho, só não consigo é declarar o evento, como eu faço com o Click, por exemplo. Esse eu consigo. Achei que para keypress, keydown, não fosse necessário declarar, mas quando eu crio meu evento no Code Behind, me dá erro no textbox. Veja meus códigos. 
XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtTara" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="161,130,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void txtTara(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == ',')
    {
        //troca o . pela virgula
        e.KeyChar = ',';

        //Verifica se já existe alguma vírgula na string
        if (txtTara.Text.Contains(","))
        {
            e.Handled = true; // Caso exista, aborte 
        }
    }

    //aceita apenas números, tecla backspace.
    else if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && !(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Esse código eu copiei aqui no SOpt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tá fazendo uma enorme confusão.

Antes de mais nada, [`KeyPressEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) não é um **evento** é só uma classe usada para passar parâmetros para o evento de `KeyPress`.

Então, isso não existe. Esta classe é oriunda do Windows Forms, não faz sentido tentar usá-la porque seu elemento não é deste *namespace*.

Para WPF o que se usa é [`KeyEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void txtTara_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { }
```

Segundo, não existe evento `KeyPress` em WPF, você vai ter que usar o `KeyDown`.

Terceiro, altere o nome do método para `txtTara_KeyPress`. Porque: 1) já existe um elemento com este nome (o próprio componente); e 2) este é o padrão de nomenclatura do C#.

E, por último, é necessário vincular o evento ao elemento visual. De alguma forma o visual precisa saber que existe um evento disparado, não existe magia para descobrir isso.

Para vincular um evento a um componenen, é necessário declarar no XAML.

Por exemplo:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtTara" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="161,130,0,0"  
         TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Width="120" KeyDown="txtTara_KeyPress"/>
```

Comment: Linq, eu preciso declarar no xaml alguma coisa, como fazemos com os eventos Click? Dessa forma assim, dá erro.

Comment: Tava editando agpra

Comment: Tá dando erro de Violação da Regra de Nomenclatura para o txtTara, como se já existisse dois caras desses.

Comment: Claro, meu jovem. Você colocou o mesmo nome pro componente e pro evento

Comment: Mudei para txtTara_KeyDown, como eu faço para Click, mas adicionei alguns using e não reconhece Keys e nem KeyChar. E pior, não há sugestão para isso. Creio que eles são do WinForm, correto?

Comment: É porque eles não são parte da classe `KeyArgs`. Você vai ter que redigir o código usando essa classe. Não vai adiantar copiar um código de WinForms e esperar que funcione numa boa.

Comment: Eu sei, é que esse código esta numa pergunta com wpf. Mas vou dar uma lida aqui e vê como fazer isso. De qulquer forma, a pergunta original foi respondida e já marquei como resposta.